# Incorrect results when concatenating three columns in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, concatenation

I have a database (in SQL Server 2008) with individual parts of a website URL, and I am trying to concatenate them to create the full URL. Lets say this is my data:

```
                 --table1
--------server-------|---facility---|---site---|
https://example.com  |     wah      |   blah   |
https://example2.com |     foo      |   bar    |
```

I want to output this:

```
https://example.com/wah/blah/
https://example2.com/foo/bar/
```

I tried the queries below and all returned the same result:

```
select server + '/' + facility + '/' + site + '/' from table1

select {fn CONCAT(server, {fn CONCAT(facility, site)})} from table1

select left(server, 128) + '/' + left(facility, 128) + '/' + left(site, 128) + '/' 
    from table1

select convert(varchar(1024), server) +  '/' + convert(varchar(1024), facility)
        + '/' + convert(varchar(1024), site) + '/'
    from table1
```

All of these queries output this result:

```
https://example.com
https://example2.com
```

If I try to run the code below it returns the proper result:

```
select 'aa' + '/' + 'bb'
--this code returns "aa/bb"
```

Because of this, I do not believe that it is an error in my software. I also tried converting the data to `varchar(1024)` and then concatenating with no luck.

I am not sure if there is some setting that I need to change, if the data that I have is corrupted in some way, or if my code is incorrect. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need any additional information.

**________________________SOLUTION_______________________**

Thanks so much everybody. This saved me a huge headache.

The end result was that there was an non-printable character at the end of each column. I used the below code to get the desired result:

```
select left(server, len(server)-1)+ '/' +left(facility, len(facility)-1)+ '/' +left(room, len(room)-1)+ '/' 
    from table1
```

This output:

```
https://example.com/wah/blah/
https://example2.com/foo/bar/
```

Again, thanks to everyone that helped out!

Comment: Give type of facility and site

Comment: Server is varchar(512).
Facility and site are varchar(128).

Comment: This works correctly on my machine.

Comment: works fine for me...non-reproduciable

Comment: Works fine on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f54ce/1/0.

Comment: `SELECT facility,LEN(facility),DATALENGTH(facility), site, LEN(site), DATALENGTH(site) FROM table1`; please give output, are you sure there is no other non-printable character?

Comment: Sorry, see the edit above. I have no idea why it doesn't work on my machine... Everything I have seen says it should. it runs with no errors and outputs the wrong result.

Comment: @lad2025 Perfect, this was the issue.

Comment: You solution is not generic, you should sanitize input. What if you have 2 characters at the end instead? Btw. what character it was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this works, it's the same data, datatype and query you've told us:

```
DECLARE @table table (server varchar(512), facility varchar(128), site varchar(128))

INSERT INTO @table
VALUES ('https://example.com','wah','blah'),
       ('https://example2.com','foo','bar')


select server + '/' + facility + '/' + site + '/' from @TABLE


select left(server, 128) + '/' + left(facility, 128) + '/' + left(site, 128) + '/' 
    from @TABLE

select convert(varchar(1024), server) +  '/' + convert(varchar(1024), facility)
        + '/' + convert(varchar(1024), site) + '/'
    from @TABLE
```

Comment: This works correctly.... I think lad2025 might be on to something with the non-printable character. The data length is consistently 1 character longer than the displayed text. Verifying...

Comment: @tesseract Check using Notepad++ show all characters, I guess you had  BOM

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if your values are being stored as `char()` or as space padded strings.  Try this:

```
select rtrim(server) + '/' + rtrim(facility) + '/' + rtrim(site) + '/'
from table1
```

Comment: You were on the right track, there was a null character at the end of each value that was causing errors. I used the code above to fix it. Thanks for the help!